# Display particular loggedin user name

Tags: php, html, css

I want to display the particular username after login successful. by using session I am calling my username. But it is displaying all user names.

Please give suggestion to display only particular username.
Here is my code.

**In session :**

```php
$_SESSION ['admin_name'] = $row['name'];
$admin_name = $_SESSION['admin_name'];
```

**Inserting in to DB :**

```php
 $sql = "INSERT INTO account_info (name)
         VALUES ( '$admin_name')";
```

**Displaying :**

```php
<?php
    $count = 1;
    $sel_query = "Select * from account_info ORDER BY id;";
    $result = mysql_query($sel_query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
?>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
<?php 
        $count++; 
    }
?>
```

I think while displaying I need to filter name. Please reply to me anybody knows how to filter.

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: In your select query, you need to use WHERE to select the user u want ! and also remove ";" after id in your query !

Comment: and dont forgot `session_start()`

Comment: For info: as I can see, you are new in PHP, so don't use MySQL_, learn PDO which is easier and more secure if you use it correctly !

Comment: @Soheyl: yah u r right, try to use prepared statement this will help u to prevent SQL attack

Comment: did u checked print_r($_SESSION)

Answer (score 0):

You should re-approach this as it's poor design, but to get what you want to achieve:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['name'] == $_SESSION['admin_name']) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or even better...

`$sel_query="Select name from account_info WHERE name = '$admin_name'";`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sel_query="Select * from account_info WHERE name = '$admin_name' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save session values into database to show it after login successful.

Only store it into session array like this:

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['name'];
```

and  in login page check this session array is set or not.If set then display it
like:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) { echo $_SESSION['user_name']; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the all username because of this query:

```
Select * from account_info ORDER BY id;
```

This will return all user data, you need to add username in WHERE clause for particular user as:

```
Select * from account_info WHERE name = '$admin_name';
```

*More important, i didn't see [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) function in your code, don't forgot to use this, otherwise you can't get the `$_SESSION` values.*

*Other important thing, your code is open for SQL Injection, you can use [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for preventing SQL Attack. This will help you: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*

*Very Special point, `mysql_*` is deprecated and closed in PHP 7.*

**Side Notes:**

*In your current query, no need to use `ORDER BY id` because when you use `WHERE` for particular user this part should be useless here.*

*Don't know, where are you using `$count++;` in your requirement, you need to print only particular user data so this is also useless here.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer,

Comment: I have session_start().

Comment: But if i write  Select * from account_info WHERE name = '$admin_name';

Comment: @Keerthi: u need to check your values `$admin_name`

Comment: @Keerthi: `print_r($_SESSION);`  use this and share the result

Comment: If I write Select * from account_info all names are showing. I don't think it is problem with name

Comment: u want to display specific user info which name available in session @Keerthi `print_r($_SESSION);` and share the result before your query

Comment: @Keerthi: did u checked?

Comment: I have added my output image.I ma getting all names as shown in the picture. Where i can write print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: @Keerthi: add before your query and you will get an array please share the result